# How to dynamically change the height of an empty div using Javascript onclick and restore with onScroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick, onscroll

1. Context: I have a button on the top of the page in the header, and I want visitors to jump to the form section which is at a lower position on the same page. For some unchangeable factors, the form is partially hidden under the header after page jump, so I am thinking of creating a new div before the form and change the height of the div to push the form down after jumping. Then, when users scroll again on the page, the height should go back to 0.
2. Problem: When I click on the DemoButton for the first time, the div height doesn't change and the form goes under header, but the second time it works. I don't know how to fix that.

The basic html structure is shown as following:

```
<div>
<a href="#demoForm" id="DemoButton">
<button>request demo</button>
</a>
</div>
<div id="space"></div>
<from id="demoForm">...</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function comparison() {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", reset, false);
  var demo = document.getElementById('DemoButton');
  demo.onclick = uniform;
}


function reset() {
    document.getElementById('Space').style.height = '0';
}

function uniform() {
    document.getElementById('Space').style.height = '160px';

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I know a lot of people are using newer CSS for reactive headers these days. I believe it's done using `media queries`, and I might suggest researching it some more. (I have some experience, it was very easy and cool too.)

Ideally, you'd want something like this to happen in CSS without JavaScript at all. See if you can get it figured out that way.

Using very light Javascript, it seems the easiest thing to do would be to just offset the scroll by the height of the header once the button has been clicked. You can hard-code the header height or calculate it dynamically.

So...

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;   $ = document                ;
;   id = 'getElementById'       ;
                    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;

onload = function (e)
{
    $[id]('DemoButton')
    .   onclick = function offset(e)
        {
            document.body.scrollTop -= $[id]('Header').offsetHeight;
        }
    ;
}
```

#### Notes

You may have to wrap it in a 5ms setTimeout. Easy enough.

I don't remember all the cross-browseryness. There might be a need to `parseInt` or use `document.documentElement`. But at least you don't have cross-browser scroll events to deal with now, so this should be nice.